# Перетаскиваемый элемент без скролла

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, drag-n-drop

Как сделать чтобы если элемент больше по ширине и высоте размеров экрана то скроллы не появлялись а было как у гугл-карт или яндекс-карт можно перетаскиванием двигать.Что-то связанное с draggable. Еще такую же реализацию видел у больших графиков d3.js

Comment: Никто не сможет мне помочь?

Comment: В чем дело? Неужели никто с таким не работал?

Comment: Уважаемый Степан! Я ни за что не поверю, что никто этим вопросом не занимался. ЧТо никто не работал с d3.js гугл/яндекс картами. Хотите сказать, что все работают на jquery и делают анимацию с аяксами? Это не ахти какая сложная задача. Эта задача встречается в каждом плагине jquery.

Comment: То есть фабрикой вы поделиться не можете?

Comment: как и что должно быть

Comment: Степан. вы не правы. Если я начну конкурс, думаю найдутся те, кто фабрику да и сделает.
А зачем вы из себя упрямца строите я не пойму.

Comment: Степан, вы совсем не хотите меня понимать. Я не говорю про решение.

Comment: То есть расписать, как избавить от скролла, при  элементе большем ширины экрана и передвигать его с помощью draggable или стрелочками это готовое решение?
Мне нужно узнать, как засунуть этот элемент,чтобы скролла не было. Или это тоже вам сложно?

Comment: Которые вы почистили. Ничего. напишу сам.

Comment: Как успехи? Не поделитесь решением?